# Running Blazor app gives debug error at startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I just created a boiler plated Blazor application: WASM and Core Hosted.
When selecting the Server as startup project and starting the whole application by launching Chrome I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the log from the output tab in VS :

[logFile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15-pTm4ZrSwS8P9e1KNxp1sOkUvlKkgwJ/view?usp=sharing)

The thing is that if I select Edge as browser where to run the application and Edge is not running, it starts fine. Meaning that I run the app, Edge will start, the application starts correctly. If Edge is already running instead with some tab open, and I start the application I have the same problem as in Chrome.
Another thing I notice is that when this problem occurs, whether in Chrome or Edge, the tab that is being opened from VS is pointing to "about:blank".. so it doesn't even point to my localhost application, while in Edge (when it works) it goes directly and correctly to localhost:44320

Question: might it be relatable to the fact that the window opened automatically by VS is not debuggable? For example when I run the app with Edge selected as default browser, and do shift+alt+d I end up here:

[image]

Makes me feel like any opened window from VS is not debuggable by default.